# Filtering on Range of Dates contour

Tags: datetime, palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

My data is as following:

```
Date_Column
-------------------------------
Aug 29, 2022 1:23:41 PM +02:00
Sep 25, 2022 6:21:56 PM +02:00
-------------------------------
```

Goal is to have a filter in contour dashboard where a user can filter data as shown in the picture.
[image: selecting range of dates]

Can someone please let me know how to implement the same in Contour Foundry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the user to be able to select the date range when viewing the analysis rather than when the analysis is being created.

Take a look at the parameterization section of the Contour documentation:
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/contour/analysis-parameterize/
You can specify a `range_start` and a `range_end` parameter and use those values in a filter board (https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/contour/boards-filter/#filter-board) as you would with fixed values.